# Add the IP address to the "GET" request with Lighttpd

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

With the mod_rewite I want to send to my destination the IP address that made the request as a "GET" parameter, like

```
rewrite-once = (".*" => ".*?ip=$HTTP[remoteip]")
```

I tried with `%a`, `%h`, `".*?ip=" + $HTTP[remoteip]`.

Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] =~ "^(.*)$" {
    url.rewrite-once = ("^(.*)$" => "$1?ip=%1")
}
```

You can use the `%` backrefrences to replace the match in the conditional.